# Black border around fading in PNG with IE8, but not IE7 or IE6

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser

Here is my site:
http://smartpeopletalkfast.co.uk/ppr14/

Their are some PNGs that fade in which also have transparency. When I test on IE8 this creates a black border around them while they fade in, which disappears once they've finished this animation.

I believe this is happening as IE can only deal with one type of transparency and fading in means its having to deal with two. What surprising me though is that the fade works fine with IE7 and IE6, which or course are older browsers.

I noticed this problem a while back and as I remember changing the PNG from 24 to 8, and I think this fixed it for IE8. Im now testing with IE8 on a brand new computer so im wondering if this could happen for another reason?

If anyone can look at the link with IE8 please tell me if your seeing the black borders or not.
Thanks

NOTE- the border is around the pink writing, its not a rectangle around the PNG file.

Also, its hard to say without seeing it in action, but if the border was white and not black this may look OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im looking at it on IE8 now and there are no black borders. Im having the same issue. did changing the pngs from 24 to 8 solve the issue?

Comment: To be honest I cant remember which version of the site that link is for. Its probably is the version that was giving me the trouble, but im away from my computer that has IE so i cant check. This issue gave me so many headaches that in the end I used a fixed width design so I didnt need the alpha transparency of PNGs so I could use JEPGs instead. Thanks anyway.